# How does webpack or node know how pick a plugin from node_modules?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack

I was recently using a react pakage and importing like so:

`import ReactRegionSelect from 'react-region-select';`

Now how does react know in my case where to import `react-region-select` from ?

I.E. if i were building the plugin `react-region-select`, which can be found HERE.

do i need to build it in a way that webpack or guld or node knows where to pick it from , considering it will be in `node_modules` ?

or is it just because in my package.json file i have the property `name: 'react-region-select'`, that webpack, gulp or node knows where to pick it from ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It checks node_modules folder by default.

You would need to publish to npm to use it in another project remotely.

Yes, using the name. NPM uses the published name to download the module under the same name when resolving dependancies.

https://webpack.js.org/concepts/module-resolution/#module-paths
https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolvemodules